Horror film where a dad returns from dead, causes trouble for his children's mom
I watched a horror movie when I was 6. I do not remember much but here's what I can remember. A guy has a wasp fly into his ear and his ear starts bleeding. The main characters are a mum a son and a daughter. The dad was dead and comes back to life. He tries getting his kids to side with him and cause some sort of trouble on the mum I think. The daughter does not get involved but the son does. The dad ends up being killed I think. I don't remember much as I was young do you think you could name the film ? 

It would help if we knew when you were 6. Also, was the movie in English? In color? Any other facts will help.

It was in colour and it would of Been 2001 when I watched it on tv.

You use the term, "mum" which leads me to believe you're English (or close to it), so does that mean it was on non-US television?

Sounds like  Amityville: Dollhouse from 1996. From an online review:

The Martin family moves into a new home with high hopes... The family consists of father Bill, his kids Todd and Jessica, Bill's new wife Claire and her son by another man Jimmy... Bill finds a dollhouse in an old shed on his land. Turns out it is an exact mini replica of the original house in Amityville complete with little dolls that would best be described as marsmallow voodoo dolls.  He brings the dollhouse house inside and leaves it in the garage.  The dollhouse lights up by itself when its alone and immediately things go wrong in the house.

At some point Jimmy's real father comes back from the dead and tries to convince Jimmy to kill Bill, but in the end, Jimmy chooses to kill his zombie father with a voodoo doll. The movie is currently available on Youtube, and around 44:15, you can see a wasp crawling into a man's ear.

I think that's the one thank you so much been trying to find it since I was six I'm 19 now haha

Happy to hear. :) Don't forget to click on the V sign to close the question.
